# Can Linux be made to honour IPv6 Route Advertisement preferences?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipv6

Bottom Line Up Front: I can't get a Linux box receiving RAs to use the [RFC4191](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4191) "Default Router Preference" value to prefer higher-priority routes.  Instead, whichever default route it learnt first is what it uses, to the detriment of all.  Am I missing a config option, or a kernel upgrade, or am I just [doomed for all time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsiKOJOXMJU)?

Long version:

I've got a network with a HA default gateway (VRRP/keepalived).  The upstream ISP is routing a /48 to the gateway, and I then carve off /64 chunks to assign to the machines in my infrastructure (so they can assign globally-routable addresses to the containers they run).  Each machine then advertises its container /64 to the rest of the network via radvd (with `AdvDefaultLifetime 0` to show it doesn't have a default route).  The gateway boxes *also* have containers running, so they have their own /64 and advertise that, but with `AdvDefaultLifetime 30` because the gateways *do* have a default route.

I want to be able to do stateful firewalling on the gateway, so all traffic in both directions needs to go through the same member of the HA gateway pair.  That's OK, I can do that -- one keepalived has a higher priority, I just tell radvd on that machine to also advertise its default route at a higher priority.  This way, if the "primary" machine drops off the perch, everything will route to the other machine and we're OK.

Except... Linux doesn't appear to *do* anything with the router preference value.  I've grovelled through the kernel source, and while it carefully preserves the value in the route flags, and `rt6_score_route` even looks like it does *something* with the preference, the behaviour I've observed in production (Ubuntu 14.04 with the 3.13 kernel) is that whichever default route was learnt first is the one that gets used, regardless of which has the higher preference.

Apart from haxxing up keepalived to change radvd config files (one with `AdvDefaultLifetime 30`, when `MASTER`, and another with `AdvDefaultLifetime 0` when `BACKUP`) and reloading radvd whenever keepalived promotes/demotes, what can I do to ensure that routes with higher preference in the RA get preferred?

Comment: Have you tried a more recent (and more importantly, a stable) kernel?

Comment: No.  Do you have any reason to believe it would help?  There's no changes to RA route preference handling in `net/ipv6/route.c` in `v3.13..6f21c96a7`, so it doesn't look like it, but if you've got experience that says otherwise, please share.

Comment: Nothing specific. I just don't have any reason to trust a non-LTS non-stable kernel (and why Canonical chose to use one in an "LTS" distro is still a mystery).

Answer (score 1):

Recent Linux kernels have the feature that you ask for. If you configure the kernel, set `CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF`, see `Networking support -> Networking options -> The IPv6 protocol -> Router Preference (RFC 4191) support`. You may need to recompile the kernel if your distro defaults to switch this feature off.

Comment: `CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF=y` on my 4.4.6 kernel. That explains a lot.

Comment: When you say "recent", you mean "since 2006"?  That config option (and the associated sysctl, `accept_ra_rtr_pref`) was introduced in `930d6ff`, and went into kernel 2.6.17.  It's also *definitely* enabled in my kernel, because that's how non-default routes get encoded in RAs.